# The navigation property '' must be configured in OnModelCreating with an explicit name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When i do migration, i have the exception

> The navigation property 'Property.UserProperty' must be configured in 'OnModelCreating' with an explicit name for the target shared-type entity type, or excluded by calling 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore()'

I have 3 classes - User, Company, Property. User must contain Property and Company, and also Company must contain Property and User.

User must have many companies and many properties,
Company must have only one User (owner) and many Properties and Properties must contain a Dictionary<object, string> that has the properties

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ICollection<Property> Properties {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Company> Companies {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Property : BaseEntity
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public Dictionary<string, object> UserProperty { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class Company : BaseEntity
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public Guid PropertyId { get; set; }
        public Property CompanyProperties { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

And OnModelCreating -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<User>(entity => entity
                    .HasMany<Property>()
                    .WithOne(p => p.User));

            builder.Entity<Property>()
                 .HasOne(p => p.User)
                 .WithMany(u => u.Properties)
                 .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
        }
```

How to configure OnModelCreating so that it works?

Comment: What does `UserProperty` actually contain and where does it come from?

Comment: @jmcilhinney UserProperty is in the Property class, it must be so that a person clicks '+' and can make his own property

Comment: Somehow the model is confusing. What is the purpose of `UserProperty`, what does the dictionary hold? Alone from that question, it is clear why EF Core complains, because this info is not retrievable from the model.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy UserProperty is the dictionary, if user clicks '+', he inputs the name that is the key of the Dictionary and a value that is the value of the Dictionary